# Background size issue when using ng-view

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm actually trying to use Angular for a personal website.

When i'm using a simple page (without ng-view) my background image is working like a charm.
But when i'm trying to render a template with ng-view my background image size is totaly wrong.

Here is my CSS :

```
#wrap {
    background-color: #303030;
    background-image: url(../img/bg1.jpg);
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I assume that it may come from the fact that Angular pre-render my template but I have no idea how I could solve it ...

I already tried to use a directive and calling it within my view with ng-style but it doesn't work ...

I hope someone already faced this problem before and may help me =)

Comment: I bet the html that you're including the the ng-view is messing it up.  As a test yry cutting and pasting that HTML directly into the parent (removing the ng-view for a minute), see if it looks the same

Comment: Yep I already tried that and it work if i do so.
How could I reproduce the same behavior with template ?

Comment: Any luck with "Inspect Element"  It would show css changes'

Comment: Only one differences, when I put the element in the index page the height of my background image evolve according my windows size. If I put it on a separate template, the height stay the same.

Comment: I tested different things and my conclusion is that angular can't determine my screen size or something like that when it push the template into my page. If I change manually the height (in px) it work just fine, but fail when i ask to auto define my height.

Comment: What did you end up going?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution !

I'm using ng-view with a div as so : `<div ng-view></div>` so when i was using all my template html was rendered within this div.

I just explicitly set my height to 100% in this div : `<div ng-view style="height:100%"></div>` and it now work.

Don't really know if it's a bug or a big lack of HTML experience.

Comment: this in-line style is also not working with my template it looks fine in normal screen size if i shrink the window are try to view it on smaller device then the image after the scroll become disappear